# What sequence of offer/answer exchange is correct when webrtc-connection is beeing established?

Tags: webrtc

When two peers in my program in javascript (Firefox 112) try to establish webrtc-connection, I have faced with a problem:

Step1) peer1 has created an offer and sent it to peer2, peer2 has received the offer, created an answer and returned it to the peer1.
Both sides added it's tracks and sent each other.
In that point peer2 has got `track` event showed video received from peer1, but peer1 has not got `track` and not showed video of peer2.

Step2) Here I block further negotiations (do not process `negotiationneeded` event, whose handler creates new offer).

Step3) However if I allow peer2 create your offer and repeat all mentioned actions, then peer2 will get `track` event and show video received from peer1.

Step4) If I do not block further process then `negotiationneeded` events alternately occur on peer 1, then on peer 2, then on peer 1, etc. causing constant calling RTCPeerConnection.createOffer() and infinite negotiation loop, though both peers show video of each other.

The questions are:

1. Should BOTH peers make it's own offers to each other so that each of them can show video ?
   Or is it enough for peer1 to create one offer and for peer2 to create one answer? So, is it necessary step3?
2. When the `negotiationneeded` event is fired ? What circumstances could potentially lead to constant firing the `negotiationneeded` event in Step4 ?

Comment: Check when and how you are adding the tracks. addTrack is preferable over addTransceiver which can get you into a bad situation like the one you are describing.

Comment: @Philipp Hancke, I don't use addTransceiver  at all - only addTracks. I am confused that if the peer calls createOffer(), then it's tracks are sent, but if it calls createAnswer() only, then it's tracks are not seen!